# pass dict with array as value to controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This code returns keys and values from my dict

```
$.map(dict, function (value, key) {
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

output:

```
0 ["19,0,0,0", "23,0,0,0", "21,0,0,0", "22,0,0,0", "20,0,0,0"]
1 ["68,0,0,0", "69,0,0,0", "70,0,0,0", "71,0,0,0", "72,0,0,0", "73,0,0,0", "74,0,0,0", "75,0,0,0"]
2 ["115,0,0,0", "114,0,0,0"]
```

So, in my opinion it is a `Dictionary <string,string[]>`

I want to pass the dict to controller

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/Home/SomeAction',
   type: 'GET',
   data: { categoryId: categoryId, traitValues: dict }
});

public ActionResult SomeAction(int categoryId, Dictionary<string,string[]> traitValues){...}
```

And here is a problem. In controller key dictionary is ok (0,1,2). But value is empty.

So how I can pass my dict from js to controller?

Comment: If the key is always the ordinal number depicting the value's position in the "dict" which increases by one by every value, can't your object then just be mapped to a `List<string[]>`?

Comment: it's a helpful idea and works

Comment: In order to bind to a dictionary your json needs to be in the format shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297075/transmit-javascript-object-into-controller-action-as-dictionary/28298048#28298048)

Comment: Please check this answer to see if it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026670/javascript-array-to-mvc-controller