# JavaScript Array to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple JavaScript array that I am trying to pass to a controller

```
function SubmitData()
{
    var operationCollection = new Array();

    var test1 = { name: "Bill", age: "55", address: "testing" };
    operationCollection.push(test1);
    var test2 = { name: "Ben", age: "55", address: "testing" };
    operationCollection.push(test2);
    var test3 = { name: "Flo", age: "55", address: "testing" };
    operationCollection.push(test3);


    var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(operationCollection);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/AddPerson",
        datatype: JSON,
        data: { methodParam: dataToPost },
        traditional: true

    });
}
```

The C# controller has a class

```
public class newEntry
{

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

}
```

and the method

```
public void AddPerson(List<newEntry> methodParam)
{

    foreach (newEntry item in methodParam)
    {
      string name =  item.age + item.address;

    }
}
```

When I run the code in debug, the value passed to the controller method is always NULL or 0. I can't seem to get the array to pass correctly. I have read on previous posts that `traditional: true` will fix this... it doesn't for me though. Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried passing it as `data: dataToPost` instead? You're currently passing an object containing the array instead of the array itself.

Comment: It needs to be `data: JSON.stringify({ methodParam: operationCollection }),` and add the `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8,` options (and note that `traditional: true,` is not required). You should also use `url: '@Url.Action("AddPerson", "Home")',` to ensure the url is correctly generated

Comment: Thanks Stephen - that sorted it.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the signature of your method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddPerson(List<newEntry> methodParam)
```

Also as Gavin stated use `data: dataToPost`