# ASP MVC post Dictionary<int, int>

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to post dictionary to server. My code works fine.

Server-side:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SomeMethod(Dictionary<string, string> someData) {
    SomeAction();
    return null;
}
```

Client-side:

```
postMethod = function() {
    var someData = {};
    someData["1"] = "1";
    someData["2"] = "2";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SomeMethod/',
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            someData: someData
        }),
    });
    return false;
};
```

But if i change type of `someData` in controllers method to `Dictionary<int, int>` and try to pass

```
someData[1] = 1;
someData[2] = 2;
```

`someData` in controllers method is empty.

Why? And what difference between passing dictionary of string and dictionary of integer?

Comment: You are doing a different thing in javascript. `someData["1"] = "1"` is assigning 1 to `someData.1` whereas `someData[1]` is setting element 1 of the array `someData` to 1. Inspect the json that gets submitted it will be totally different. Remeber javascript doesn't have dictionaries or associative arrays, it just supports a similar syntax for assigning value to objects.

Comment: ok, i see, but is there the way to pass 'something' for `public JsonResult SomeMethod(Dictionary<string, string> someData)` or i need to parse dictionary of string on server-side code?

Comment: The only way to pass integers to that controller is via `SomeMethod(Dictionary<string, int> someData)`, passing `someData["1"] = 1;` from the JS code.

Comment: Another technique for posting a dictionary is described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297075/transmit-javascript-object-into-controller-action-as-dictionary/28298048#28298048)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try using Array ..

var someData = new Array();
someData.key1 = 1;
someData.key2 = 2;

$.ajax({
    url: '/SomeMethod/',
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        someData: someData
    }),
});
```