# cant pass array to dictionary in ASP.NET MVC - Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have action Method like this :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public virtual JsonResult AddCombination(Dictionary<Guid,Guid> combinations)
    {

        return Json(new { result = false });
    }
```

and I have script to send some data with jquery Ajax like this :

```
 $(document).on('click', '#addcombination', function () {
        var combinationarray = {};

        $(".drpcombination").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('name');
            var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
            if ($(selected).val().trim().length > 0) {
                combinationarray[id] = $(selected).val();
            }
        });

        if (Object.keys(combinationarray).length > 0) {

            $.ajax({
                url: $('#url').data('addcombination'),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                //data: {combinations:combinationarray},
                data:  combinationarray ,
                success: function (data) {

                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function (response) {

                }
            });
        }

    });
```

always combinatios are null.
firebug Result like this :
[image]

I try some ways but cant get any result .

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you use a dictionary. You will find this much easier to post an array of objects.In any case you will at least need to stringify the data and use `contentType: 'json'`

Comment: @StephenMuecke In View , I have some dropdown like Attribute and attributeOption , in action method i need AttributeId and AttributeOptionId. I add `contentType:'json'` but don't work

Comment: you cannot pass dictionary parameter. Here is what you can do. Create a class eg.MyClass with 2 properties of guid type. Your function parameter will be of type List<MyClass>. From client create the json array. Once you get the data in the method, convert to dictionary.

Comment: `var combinationarray = []; combinationarray.push({ AttributeId: 1, AttributeOptionId: 2 };` and `data: JSON.stringify({combinations: combinationarray}),` and `contentType:'json'` will post back to `List<MyModel> combinations` where `MyModel` contains those 2 properties

Comment: If you do want a dictionary, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297075/transmit-javascript-object-into-controller-action-as-dictionary/28298048#28298048) for one option

Comment: @StephenMuecke I add viewmodel like this `AddCombination(List<testvm> combinations)` but its null , and add `  contentType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ combinations: combinationarray }),`

Comment: and this ViewModel :` public class testvm
    {
        public Guid AttributeId { get; set; }
        public Guid AttributeOptionId { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: @UthmanRahimi, The code in my previous comment does work, so you have not done it correctly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke see https://jsfiddle.net/e5bqdmsh/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110156/discussion-between-uthman-rahimi-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for help , I forgot add `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` , thanks a lot