# Is there a way to get firefox to not automatically url-decode values assigned to document.location.hash?

Tags: javascript, url, encoding

I'm using document.location.hash to preserve state on the page,  and I'm putting url-encoded key value pairs up there, separated by "&" chars.  So far so good.

However I'm running into an annoying problem on Firefox -- Firefox will quietly url-decode the hash value on the way in, so when you get it out later it's been decoded.

I can patch the problem by detecting when I'm running on firefox and calling encodeURIComponent on everything *twice* on the way in, but obviously that is hideous and I don't really want to do that.

Here's a simple example, where I encode "=" as "%3D", put it in the hash, and when I get it out later it's been turned back into "=" automatically:

```
// on the way in::
document.location.hash = "foo=" + encodeURIComponent("noisy=input");

//then later.....
// on the way out: 
var hash = document.location.hash;
kvPair = hash.split("=");

if (kvPair.length==2) {
    console.log("that is correct.")
} else if (kvPair.length==3) {
    console.log("oh hai firefox, this is incorrect")
}
```

I have my fingers crossed that there's maybe some hidden DOM element that firefox creates that represents the actual (un-decoded) hash value?

but bottom line -- has anyone run into this and found a better solution than just doing browser detection and calling encodeURIComponent twice on Firefox?

NOTE: several other questions I think have the same root cause. Most notably this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834609/malformed-uri-in-firefox-not-ie-using-encodeuricomponenet-and-setting-hash

Comment: I'm afraid there's no good way than a different procedure in firefox until they someday fix the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=483304 . An option may be to extract the hash from window.location using String-functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against using the hash value to preserve the state. Hash is supposed to point to object's fragment-id, as explained in [RFC 1630](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1630.txt)

> This represents a part of, fragment of, or a sub-function within, an
>      object. (...) The fragment-id follows the URL of the whole object from which it is
>      separated by a hash sign (#).

Is there anything stopping you from using cookies to preserve the state? Cookies are simple enough to use in JS, [described on Geko DOM Reference pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie), and would do the trick quietly, without appending values to the URL which is never pretty.

If you absolutely have to use hash though, you may want to consider replacing '=' with some other character, e.g. ":".

Comment: I have the same problem as author does. Using cookie isn't a solution when you need to propagate the state sharing the url. Any other solution that is cross-browser compatible? Ideally we'd have html5 onpopstate.

Comment: We have a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835784/firefox-automatically-decoding-encoded-parameter-in-url-does-not-happen-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is change the "=" to something else using

`var string = string2.replace("=", "[$equals]")`

You may have to run the line above a couple of times, depending on how many "=" there are.

Then same process you had as above.

NB If you require it for further code, you can replace [$equals] back to "=" after splitting the hash into an array.